# SAS rsubmit/signon remote-session-id naming constraints?

Tags: sas

Using E.G. and on SAS 9.4 v3 with a Grid environment.

The syntax I'm using for rsubmit is:
rsubmit *remote-session-id* *additional options*

I'd like to use an 8 digit numeric code for the id to make life easy for myself.

In the below code, session 20161000 and 30161001 get cancelled, but 10161000 and 16100040 are accepted.

What are the naming constraints around *remote-session-id* ? Here's a doc but it doesn't cover it...:
[SAS/CONNECT(R) 9.4 User's Guide, Third Edition. RSUBMIT Statement](http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/connref/67933/HTML/default/viewer.htm#p1eyablk3vvdlkn1h5euyczvt585.htm)

```
%let rc=%sysfunc(grdsvc_enable(_all_,server=SASApp));

options autosignon;
options NOSIGNONWAIT;

rsubmit 10161001 wait=no;
data test1;
    set sashelp.class;
    run;
endrsubmit;

rsubmit 20161000 wait=no;
    data test2;
    set sashelp.cars;
    run;
endrsubmit;

rsubmit 30161001 wait=no;
data test3;
    set sashelp.shoes;
    run;
endrsubmit;

rsubmit 16100040 wait=no;
data test4 ;
    set sashelp.buy;
run;
endrsubmit;

waitfor _all_ ;
signoff _all_;
```

NOTE: Remote session ID 10161001 will use the grid service *ALL*.
NOTE: Background signon to 10161001 in progress.

NOTE: Remote session ID 20161000 will use the grid service *ALL*.
NOTE: Background signon to 20161000 in progress.
**ERROR: Remote submit to 20161000 canceled.**
NOTE: The link to 20161000 has been terminated. You must SIGNON to reestablish the link.

NOTE: Remote session ID 30161001 will use the grid service *ALL*.
NOTE: Background signon to 30161001 in progress.
**ERROR: Remote submit to 30161001 canceled.**
NOTE: The link to 30161001 has been terminated. You must SIGNON to reestablish the link.

NOTE: Remote session ID 16100040 will use the grid service *ALL*.
NOTE: Background signon to 16100040 in progress.

Comment: What if you rearrange these (20161001 then 40161001 then 10161001 then 30161001 for example)?

Comment: The order doesn't affect the issue.

Comment: Meaning 20161001 still fails?  Or the _first_ one works and beyond that fails.

Comment: I ask  because I suspect it's replacing that first digit with `_`, meaning it considers the first 3 all identical.

Comment: Affirmative, the same identifiers still fail

Comment: Oh, actually I see the 0 on the end of the second one, so it must not be that. hmm

Comment: I would crosspost on communities.sas.com then and see if one of the developers can link you to the info.

Comment: I switched the last digit in each to a different number and the ones that start with 2 and 3 still fail. Will check with SAS to see what's going on just to find out, but will adopt the status-quo in SAS land with starting things with a character. Thanks for your ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have an authoritative bit of documentation that confirms this, but in my experience the following rules apply when naming SAS/CONNECT sessions:

- Must consist only of letters, numbers and underscores
- Must be at most 8 characters long
- Must not start with a number

Possibly coincidentally, these are the same restrictions that apply to librefs and filerefs.

If you find anything else that reliably works but does not follow these rules, please let me know!

Comment: With our server setting the 8 digit session id should have worked, but it doesn't, possibly due to a bug on the SAS side as confirmed by a conversation with a SAS rep. To be safe, I'll conform to the usual SAS conventions as you have outlined... and accept your answer.